# How to prove that solution of ODE is even function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

Could you please give me some hint how to prove this statement:

If $f(x)$ is solution of $y'=4x^3e^{-|y|}$ then $f(x)$ is even function.
It is obvious that $f(x)$ increasing for all $x>0$ and decreasing for all $x<0$,
so there are $a<0,b>0$ such as $f(a)=f(b)$, but how to prove that $a=-b$ ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y(x)$ is a solution of your equation also $\tilde{y}(x):=y(-x)$ is a solution: in fact replacing $x\to -x$ you get
$$\frac{d}{dx}y(-x)=-4(-x)^3e^{-|y(-x)|}\quad\Rightarrow\quad\frac{d}{dx}\tilde{y}(x)=4x^3e^{-|\tilde{y}(x)|}$$
But since the two solution coincide for $x=0$, $y(0)=\tilde{y}(0)$, by uniqueness they have to coincide everywhere, i.e. $$y(x)=\tilde{y}(x)=y(-x)\ .$$